# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined" when trying to parse an object from an array (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I have created a way to store data the way I want in AsyncStorage. This includes:

1. Reading a variety of input (various arrays)
2. Storing the input in a local `this.state.object` that houses multiple arrays
3. Stringifying `this.state.object`
4. Storing the stringified object in a temp array
5. Assigning the array with all objects to another state, `this.state.allObjects`
6. Stringifying 'this.state.allObjects'
7. Storing stringified array in AsyncStorage

The end goal of all of this is to have an array of objects that each represent a very different instance of the same type (with different parameters etc.). It may not be the most elegant approach, but it seems to store and load fine.

The issue arises when I try to parse anything from `this.state.allObjects[x]`. Or rather, it only occurs when I need to access it in a case that is NOT right after I load it.

During my `loadFromAsync` function, I am perfectly able to execute `this.state.allObjects = JSON.parse(fromAsync);` to get the array of stringified objects and then `var display = JSON.parse(this.state.allObjects[0]).name` to retrieve the name of the first parsed object of the array.

Any time outside of this function when I try to call `var display = JSON.parse(this.state.allObjects[0]).name` or even simpler `<Text>{JSON.parse(this.state.allObjects[0]).name}</Text>` I receive the following errors:

- when running

```
const parse  = JSON.parse(this.state.allObjects[0]); 
//JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"
console.log(parse.name);
```

- and when running

```
const parse  = JSON.parse(this.state.allObjects[0]).name; 
//JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined" + null is not an object (evaluating 'JSON.parse(this.state.allObjects[0]).name
console.log(parse);
```

- and lastly while running

```
const parse  = JSON.parse(this.state.allObjects); 
//JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF + JSON Parse error: Unexpected token ','
```

I assume that `this.state.allObjects` changes somewhere within my code, or appends an extra `}` somewhere, though it really shouldn't. When I display `this.state.object` and `this.state.allObjects[0]`, their format is exactly the same visually. Adding more objects to `this.state.allObjects` and displaying each stringified component also works; it is just a matter of actually parsing these components that is not working outside the original load function.

I am extremely stuck. Any advice is appreciated. If I need to change my datatype, that's fine. It's just a bit annoying to have come this far with a stringified array of stringified objects holding arrays and not be able to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `this.state.allObjects` Already JSON object.

Try `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: In `<View>{this.state.allObjects}</View>` it perfectly displays all objects on the screen in `{"array1":"values","array2":"values"}{"array1":"values","array2":"values"}{"array1":"values","array2":"values"}` for an example of 3 objects. The contents are still Stringified.

Comment: try.. `var a = {a: '1'}; JSON.parse(a); JSON.stringift(a);`

Comment: printing 
var a results in: [object Object];
JSON.stringify(a): {"a":"1"};
JSON.parse(a): JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object";

Comment: Yeah because 'a' is already JSON object so i don't know what you need

Comment: I believe I understand how .parse and .stringify work... I am just unsure why the context change causes the errors I am seeing above.

Comment: JSON.stringify -> Object make to string like `"{"a":"1"}"` `"` is very important syntax of change object

Comment: const parse  = JSON.parse(this.state.allObjects[0]);  <<< this object is Not JSON.stringified Object!!

Comment: First you make allObjects in [0] make to JSON.stringify like this `this.state.allObjects[0] = JSON.stringify(this.state.allOjbects[0]); and try this will work

Comment: If [0] doesn't have any value will return err

Comment: stringifying `allObjects[0]` prints '"{\"array1\":\"values\",\"array2\":\"values\"}"' while parsing that stringified object results in another `JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"`

Comment: I also stringified each object before even adding it to the array. So I should just be able to parse it anywhere right?

Comment: Did you change variable this.state.allUpdates[0]? should try this.state.allObjects[0] = JSON.stringify(this.state.allOjbects[0]);

Comment: For testing, I'm actually assigning `this.state.allObjects` to a temp variable and modifying that. What would stringifying an already stringified object do for me?

Comment: I don't understand what you saying

Comment: I have a stringified object in every spot of  'this.state.allObjects[]'  and I want to read the contents of each object in the array. 'JSON.parse(this.state.allObjects[×])' does not reverse the stringify as I need it to.

Comment: Because this.state.allOjbects[x] is not JSON.stringpied string,

Comment: You wrote `"{\"array1\":\"values\",\"array2\":\"values\"}"` and i try JSON.parse("{\"array1\":\"values\",\"array2\":\"values\"}") // `{array1: "values", array2: "values"}` it's can works

Comment: JSON.parse(this.state.allObjects[×])' is not converted JSON? because this is not JSON.stringify string

Comment: I tried that example by passing `this.state.allObjects` into a function. I ran
`const testString = JSON.stringify(props.input[0]);` and `const parsed = JSON.parse(testString);`, however, the second command causes `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"`. I am calling these lines within a function where `this.state.allObjects` is parsed as a prop to be modified.

Comment: To elaborate: I have a function `function ParseObject(props){const testString = JSON.stringify(props.input[0]) ... }` and call it in my `export default class` `render(){return( ... <ParseObject input = {this.state.allObjects} />`

Comment: On that note, even if I don't call it in a component and just post `<Text>{JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.allObjects[0]))}</Text>` it doesn't work.